# Webpack postcss-loader not working when passed function

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, sass, postcss

I am working on a webpack configuration in `repo removed`. Right now when I run `npm run teststart` (which uses `webpack.development.js`) or `npm run testbuild` (which uses `webpack.production.js`), the postcss loader stylelint, autoprefixer and postcss-focus do not seem to work. However, if I pass an array instead of a function of the form () => [] to the plugins on the postcss-loader, it does work. 
So for example, if I change

```
options: {
  plugins: () => [require('autoprefixer'), require('postcss-focus')]
}
```

to

```
options: {
  plugins: [require('autoprefixer'), require('postcss-focus')]
}
```

in `webpack.production.js` it works.

But in another project the function format works fine. Trying to figure out why it isn't working here.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer- apparently postcss-loader not working right when a function is passed to the loader's options.plugins was a bug in postcss-loader v2.0.3, they fixed it in v2.0.5 and updating solved my problem. There's an issue about this on github here:

[github.com/postcss/postcss-loader/issues/218](http://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader/issues/218)